# Unable to install library functions of qdap on mac

Tags: r

I'm working on a project on R studio and I got a error message while installing qdap on my mac and running the library function.

And this is what I got.

```
install.packages('qdap')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/qdap_2.3.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4164745 bytes (4.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/0v/c58lzwxd513g64xxc0gd85rm0000gn/T//RtmphbntNA/downloaded_packages
> library('qdap')
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: maybe a folder permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is that R is not able to locate Java_home correctly.

Steps to follow:

1. Download and install Java JDK if you haven't already done so.
2. In Terminal, find java location by typing `which java`
3. Set JAVA_HOME in R as `Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = 'your java location such as /usr/bin/java')`.
4. Try reinstalling the packages openNLP, rJava, and qdap.